# Relational Databases organization

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am creating a CMS for a website that will contain news and different topics for the news pages. So I was creating one table for each topic(sports, literature etc etc) just to have a cleaner and better database organization(I thought). But I recently learned about relational databases, and found out that it's possible to achieve the same task with less tables(just 2 tables topics and content) and therefore less code(which is great). But my concern is, since this website may with time have hundreds or maybe thousands of pages, is it safe, clean, and ok to have so many pages in one table? Knowing that someday someone could hack into the site and DROP that table, and I would loose all the posts. So is there any cleaner and safe way to achieve this task, but still using the concept of relational databases?

Comment: You are confusing two topics from what I can see.  You shouldn't compromise on good DESIGN just because you are concerned about SECURITY.  These are two completely separate things.  On the design side, a decent database engine, such as mySQL or SQL Server can handle millions and millions of rows in one table.  Your hardware may be more of a limiting factor.

Comment: If you're concerned about hackers "dropping tables" then you take regular backups.... but hackers could drop many tables as easily as they could drop one table

Comment: @JLo sorry about that, so should I change the title?

Comment: Note that you might want three tables (topics, content and content_topics), if it's possible for a book about a sportsperson to be categorised as both sport and as literature

Comment: I think the question is simply invalid and you should ask two separate questions, and follow up on both.  You are correct to be questioning both of these topics, and you are on the correct path investigating relational databases - it seems you have grasped the basics already.  You are also correct to be questioning security, but you should research, learn and act upon these two things independently in my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: Yes. As JLo says in a comment above, when designing your database structure, you shouldn't be thinking mainly about security; think mainly about efficiency of data storage (ie. normalization).

If a hacker can get into your database, that's a problem no matter what tables they can access. So in terms of security, focus your energy on preventing injections and database attacks in the first place. To try to separate your data into different tables in order to protect it from hacks is like storing your gold in ten different bank vaults to protect from bank robberies; it's [security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) and it works against you every step of the way.

Instead, in terms of security:

- **Invest in a security audit for your server code if it's already written.** An expert can point you to bits of code that can have implications for unwanted database access and tell you exactly why. I'd say the learning experience you get from an audit is even more valuable than the actual concrete recommendations they make.
- **Google [SQL injection](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=sql%20injection) and read everything you possibly can on the topic.** This technique is how the majority of database hacks happen, and it's vital that you're more than familiar with what it is, what vulnerable code looks like, and how to write code that protects against it.
- **Set up excellent redundant database backup systems.** At least 2 separate ones stored in 2 different places. If a hacker DROPs one of your tables, then it will become a major inconvenience rather than a business breaker.

In terms of normalized data strucutre:

- **Store same-shaped data in the same place.** So as long as all Pages can be described / defined in terms of the same columns in a table, absolutely store them in the same table.
- **Learn about Mysql performance and indexes.** A poorly indexed / poorly structured database can grind to a halt under low traffic and under a million rows in the largest tables; a well-indexed one can behave fine with *billions* of rows. This issue becomes bigger as your traffic increases, so hopefully your budget grows accordingly and allows you to get expert help on this. Performance issues can rear their head very suddenly, so it's worth learning a good deal about them before they crash your site.
- **Don't worry too much about number of rows.** The main concern here is performance; see above. Relational databases are built to handle big tables; that's their main use case. With basic indexing techniques (e.g. add an index on every foreign key column and any other column that's commonly queried against (but primary key columns are already indexed so they don't need one)) you should be able to make it up to 1M-10M rows without major performance issues.
- **Find a way to benchmark your queries against real data.** Some performance optimizations are obvious, but as the saying goes, [premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). For example, when writing your queries, do some benchmarked experimentation to get a feel for whether it's more performant to have fewer queries (that are longer / have more JOINs) or more queries (that are smaller and faster). As a very general rule, fewer queries are better, but there are a number of cases where your app will disagree ;-) so have the infrastructure in place to test it out yourself. Same thing when adding indexes; benchmarking can give you a good gut sense for what effect indexes have on your database, and that gut sense is a very valuable thing to have.

Comment: I would upvote this twice if I could.  It's a good tip-sheet for someone just starting to learn a bit about designing relational databases.

Comment: Thanks JLo! In my experience the best way to build familiarity with Mysql is to have a GUI like SequelPro at hand so you can play with queries, add the indexes yourself and so on. Seems like many projects these days (especially in the Rails world) only access the database indirectly via a console, migration scripts and so forth; this distance from the database really makes it harder to get a feel for what's going on.

Comment: @TopherHunt thanks a lot for the help, this is very helpful, and I'll surely search for a database management tool(for linux) with a GUI to see if I can focus more on the design and have more "direct contact" with the database so that I can sharpen my skills. Once more, thank you.

Comment: @Yuran if your desktop environment is on Linux, looks like MysqlWorkbench and Navicat have native offerings. I found MysqlWorkbench a bit slow to start up but very stable; I only used it for writing queries and ignored most of its advanced features. I found Navicat somewhat unstable and unreliable (sometimes it made changes I hadn't requested) and generally won't recommend it. If your desktop is Windows or Mac but the database is on a Linux server, most Mysql GUI clients have an option to connect to a remote database via SSH. This can be a pain to set up but is 200% worth it.

Answer (score 2):

> since this website may with time have hundreds or maybe thousands of pages, is it safe, clean, and ok to have so many pages in one table?

As long as your indexes are correct you can store millions of pages in the database.

> Knowing that someday someone could hack into the site and DROP that
>   table, and I would loose all the posts.

Using one or thousand tables makes no difference here, if you can drop one table you can drop them all.